Pass params while navigating back
I am using expo-router, I have two screens ScreenA and ScreenB, from ScreenA I am navigating to screenB, in screenB I want to push data back to screenA by using router.back() or any other way, I don't want to use router.push() since I want to go back not push the previous screen on top of the stack, Is there any way to pass params while navigating back in expo-router
Here is the root layout:
 <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="index"
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="admin/screenA"
      />
    </Stack>

Here is how I am navigating to screenB:
router.push({
     pathname: './screenB',
     params: location
     ? {
     latitude: location.latitude,
     longitude: location.longitude, 
}: null,});

I am using useLocalSearchParams() to access params in both screens

You could achieve this with a hack, but the ideal way would be to either store the data in redux store or a context while you're on screen B and then access it in screen A.

@sj_959 Hmm I don’t want implement a redux store for something as small as this but isn’t there any other way, I looked at the docs but there isn’t any way specific to expo router

Solution 1
If you do not have Redux integrated in your app, you can use Context from react to share data between the two screens.
A possible implementation of the context could be as follows:
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export const SharedContext = React.createContext({
  sharedData: [],
  setSharedData: (val) => {},
});

export default function SharedDataProvider({children}) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  function setSharedData(value) {
    setData(value);
  }

  return (
    <SharedContext.Provider
      value={{
        sharedData: data,
        setSharedData,
      }}>
      {children}
    </SharedContext.Provider>
  );
}

Then, you can keep screens A & B under the same folder and add a _layout file where you can wrap the screens with the provider.
import SharedContext from "@/context/SharedContext"

export default function CommonLayout  () {
    return (
        <SharedContext>
            <Stack>
                <Stack.Screen name="screenA" />
            </Stack>
        </SharedContext>
    )
}

Then you can set the data in screen B by using the useContext hook:
import {SharedContext} from '@/context/SharedContext';

const {setSharedData} = useContext(SharedContext);

// Somewhere on the press of a button
setSharedData([]); // some data

And finally access the data in screen A when you navigate back to it.
import {SharedContext} from '@/context/SharedContext'


const {sharedData} = useContext(SharedContext);

Solution 2
You could try navigating back to screen A with router.navigate by passing the absolute path of the screen and the params you'd like to send. For instance, in screen B, you can add:
router.navigate({pathname: 'path-to-screen-A', params: {
      extraParams: {
        
      }
}})


Your solution works but does expo not have an api where we can pass params while navigating to a previous route

@RohithNambiar I have updated my answer with the second solution.
